# Counting the distinct columns(2 columns) value

Tags: sql

I have table like this

```
abc     a1
abc     a1
abc     a1
abc1    a2
abc1    a2
abc2    a3
```

i want create a table

```
abc  a1 3
abc1 a2 2
abc2 a3 1
```

Tried for distinct value in column 1 and column 2 but doesnt work well.can anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Learn basic SQL so you know what a `group by` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
select
    column1,
    column2,
    count(*) as column3
from
    YourTable
group by column1, column2
```